# jQuery :first deprecated - rewrite?

Tags: jquery

How would I re-write something like this in jQuery 3.4.1 or vanilla JS:

```
$("#ResultsTable tr:not(:first)").remove();
```

with :first being deprecated?
(https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

I need to remove all the rows other than the first one.

Comment: "The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq( 0 ). It could also be written as :lt( 1 ). While this matches only a single element, :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent."  Did you try any of that?

Comment: is the `tr` you want to excude in the `thead` ?

Comment: Otherwise `$('#ResultsTable tr').slice(1).remove()`

Comment: According to this: https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.4/    :lt() and :eq() are also deprecated. So I didn't want to try those. And I wondered if :first-child was also next to get scrapped...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.slice(startIndex)`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method

```js
$("#ResultsTable tr").slice(1).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="ResultsTable">
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

If the first row is a header, then utilize the table structure using [`thead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) and use [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove the rows in the body.

```js
$("#ResultsTable tbody").empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="ResultsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>1</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a `tbody` with a list of `tr`s you could use

```
$("#ResultsTable tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
```

If though you exclude the first because you want to keep the `thead` row then you could use

```
$("#ResultsTable tbody tr").remove();
```

to remove the normal rows and keep the headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ResultsTable tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
```

You can use `not(:first-child)` selector.

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but I assume you meant `:first-child`